# GET Ajax Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I am trying to get the name of a person through XML. I am using Jquery to get and apply the name to an html element.. I was able to debug to understand that it is getting the name of the person but its not appending it.. Any ideas? my function is syntax free but i can't seem to get why it does not work.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://support.example.com/support/api.asp?token=e6k05nbssjkjqo3qk7rd4rvr01hvlv&cmd=viewPerson',
    datatype: 'xml',
    success: function(data) {
        $(data).find('sFullName').each(function() { 
            var sf = $(this).find('text').text();
           $('span#username').append(
                $('<a />', {
                    text: sf
                })
                );            
        });

    },
    error: function() {
        console.log();
    }
});
```

Comment: syntax free?? `console.log$(...` ??

Comment: CORS, you can't make requests that are not on the same domain maybe ? What is the error in the console ?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://support.jonar.com/support/api.asp?token=e6k05nbssjkjqo3qk7rd4rvr01hvlv&cmd=viewPerson. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin is therefore not allowed access.  The console is your friend.

Comment: @Hacketo — The OP said that when the debugged it they were getting the name, so that suggests that isn't the case.

Comment: but i can see in the debug tool that its getting the XML data..

Comment: @user2752291 — You can see in *what* debug tool that *what* is getting the XML data? The Script debug tool in the browser developer tools? And the success function?

Comment: yep. i used console.log($(this).find("sFullName").text());   and i am able to see in chrome debug that it gets the name @quentin (yes the chrome dev tools)

Comment: Oh my god! Just check network tab and see what's going on

Comment: @evc — If `console.log($(this).find("sFullName").text());` is giving the expected result, why would the network tab reveal any problems?

Comment: Why would you console log that? You don't see the result in html page? Kinda XY problem

Comment: @evc — As a fairly basic debugging practise.

Comment: in the network tab the request is grabbed and i can see everything is green lol and preview the whole xml doc @evc

Comment: Use that always, it's the best way to debug http requests

Comment: @user2752291 there is no `text` inside `sFullName `, only comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each `<sFullName>` element you are finding all the `<text>` elements.

The data you are requesting looks, in part, like this:

```
<sFullName><![CDATA[Rajat Sharma]]></sFullName>
```

The element doesn't have any `<text>` elements as its descendants.

You simply want:

```
var sf = $(this).text();
```

---

```js
var data = $.parseXML("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><response><person><ixPerson>400</ixPerson><sFullName><![CDATA[Rajat Sharma]]></sFullName><sEmail><![CDATA[rajat@jonar.com]]></sEmail><sPhone></sPhone><fAdministrator>true</fAdministrator><fCommunity>false</fCommunity><fVirtual>false</fVirtual><fDeleted>false</fDeleted><fNotify>true</fNotify><sHomepage></sHomepage><sLocale><![CDATA[en-ca]]></sLocale><sLanguage><![CDATA[en-us]]></sLanguage><sTimeZoneKey><![CDATA[Eastern Standard Time]]></sTimeZoneKey><sSnippetKey><![CDATA[`]]></sSnippetKey><ixBugWorkingOn>0</ixBugWorkingOn><nType>1</nType></person></response>");

$(data).find('sFullName').each(function () {
    var sf = $(this).text();
    $('span#username').append(
    $('<a />', {
        text: sf
    }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="username"></span>
```

Comment: @Hacketo — It isn't a comment. Comments start `<!--` not `<![CDATA`

Comment: i found out what was going on! i replaced `$(data).find('sFullName').each(function () {` with `$(data).find('person').each(function () {` and `var sf = $(this).find('Text').text();` WITH `var sf = $(this).find('sFullName').text();`